# Custom php file in root folder

Tags: wordpress, include, root

So, I have a custom php file in my wordpress root folder.

I have a link in frontend `"example.com/custom.php"` that I would like to access.

How would I include this custom php in root folder in function.php so that it can be recognized by other wordpress function?

Thanks

Comment: If you want the file to be recognized by wordpress, put it inside your theme and use [include_once](http://php.net/manual/en/function.include-once.php).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add this line in your themes functions.php:

```
include(ABSPATH . 'custom.php');
```

Explanation:

Your wp-config.php should contain the following code (near the bottom of the page):

```
/** Absolute path to the WordPress directory. */
if ( !defined('ABSPATH') )
    define('ABSPATH', dirname(__FILE__) . '/');
```

They are saving the path to the wordpress installation to ABSPATH.

It will be something like "/var/www/foo/" or similar. So you can concat the ABSPATH with path to your file. If for example, your php file is located inside some folder like this "example.com/somefolder/custom.php" you would use

```
include(ABSPATH . 'somefolder/custom.php');
```

Hope this helps!